# Fill a vue form

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a form built with Vue with a hierarchy of components using `v-model` to bind the data to the model.

Now I want to fill the form programmatically. If I just update the model (data) of the top component, it has no effect on the child components since this only changes their props.

Here's an example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/411545/

When you click the 'Set to 2018-Oct' button, the model on the `myApp` is updated, but not the model of the `<mydate>` component.

Is there a way to achieve filling the form without adding watchers to `value` props (which the official guide doesn't suggest) on all components in the hierarchy?

Comment: It would better if you could share some code sample ?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: I would be better if you added your code to the question so that way future readers can see your problem should the jsfiddle get deleted and get help if they are running into the same issue

Comment: that would only help if the question had a solution :)